# Azure functions throws an error while sending D2C messages using Device Client SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I have an Even hub Triggered azure function from which I need to send D2C message to IoT hub.

I have installed Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client from NuGet. But it throws the following error while sending D2C message at `deviceClient.SendEventAsync(iotmessage)`.

> Error:
>   Unable to find assembly 'Validation, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2fc06f0d701809a7'. 
>   Are you missing a private assembly file?
>   Error occured - Could not load file or assembly 'Validation, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2fc06f0d701809a7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Code:

```
[FunctionName("TelemetryProcessor")]
        public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("telemetry", ConsumerGroup = "$Default", Connection = "TelemetryEventHubConnection")]string telemetryMessage, TraceWriter log)
        {
            try
            {
                var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IoTMessage>(telemetryMessage);  
                if (message.MessageType == MessageType.TLM)
                {
                    var device = GetiDeviceById(message.SenderId);
                    if (device != null)
                    {
                        using (var deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create("iothub.azure-devices.net",
                                  new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(device.Id, device.Key), TransportType.Mqtt))
                        {
                            message.MessageType = MessageType.TLM_HUB;
                            var iotmessage = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message.ToString()));
                            await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(iotmessage);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        log.Error($"Device Not Found");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error($"Error occured - {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What Assemblies & versions do you have in your project?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem and this is how I got it working.

Edit/Create the project.json file for the function and include the specific version of Validation.  I also found I had trouble with Json serializable until I specified an earlier version of Newtonsoft.Json as well.

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "microsoft.azure.devices.client": "1.6.1",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
        "validation": "[2.2.8]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```